# When the page refreshes, there are new workouts being created

Tags: javascript, dom, leaflet

I am working on a website that the user can log workouts in. It is a very simple website. The problem is that when the user enters a cycling or a running workout (those are the only kinds there are for now), and the user refreshes, due to local storage the workout stays on the website. However, there is a duplicate workout made with the same parameters.

On the Leaflet map, the duplicate workout resides at the same place as the user-inputted workout.

```
  _moveToPopup(e) {
    const editButton = e.target.closest('.edit__workout');
    const workoutEl = e.target.closest('.workout');
    html = ``;
    if (editButton) {
      if (workoutEl.className.includes('running')) {
        const newTitle = prompt('Enter new workout title:');
        const newDistance = prompt('Enter new distance:');
        const newDuration = prompt('Enter new duration:');
        const newSteps = prompt('Enter new steps:');
        workoutEl.innerHTML = `
          <h2 class="workout__title">${newTitle}</h2>
          <div class="workout__details">
          <button class="edit__workout">Edit Here!</button>
              <span class="workout__icon">‍♂️</span>
              <span class="workout__value">${Number(newDistance).toFixed(
                1
              )}</span>
              <span class="workout__unit">km</span>
          </div>
          <div class="workout__details">
              <span class="workout__icon">⏱</span>
              <span class="workout__value">${Number(newDuration).toFixed(
                1
              )}</span>
              <span class="workout__unit">min</span>
          </div>
          <div class="workout__details">
              <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
              <span class="workout__value">${Number(
                newDuration / newDistance
              ).toFixed(1)}</span>
              <span class="workout__unit">min/km</span>
          </div>
          <div class="workout__details">
              <span class="workout__icon"></span>
              <span class="workout__value">${Number(
                newSteps / newDuration
              ).toFixed(1)}</span>
              <span class="workout__unit">spm</span>
          </div>
      `;
      } else if (workoutEl.className.includes('cycling')) {
        const newTitle = prompt('Enter new workout title:');
        const newDistance = prompt('Enter new distance:');
        const newDuration = prompt('Enter new duration:');
        const newElevation = prompt('Enter new elevation gain:');
        workoutEl.innerHTML = `
          <h2 class="workout__title">${newTitle}</h2>
          <div class="workout__details">
          <button class="edit__workout">Edit Here!</button>
            <span class="workout__icon">‍♀️</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${Number(newDistance).toFixed(
              1
            )}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">km</span>
          </div>
          <div class="workout__details">
            <span class="workout__icon">⏱</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${Number(newDuration).toFixed(
              1
            )}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">min</span>
          </div>
          <div class="workout__details">
            <span class="workout__icon">⚡️</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${Number(
              newDistance / newDuration
            ).toFixed(1)}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">km/h</span>
          </div>
          <div class="workout__details">
            <span class="workout__icon">⛰</span>
            <span class="workout__value">${Number(newElevation).toFixed(
              1
            )}</span>
            <span class="workout__unit">m</span>
          </div>
        </li>
        `;
      }
    } `
```

https://pastebin.com/bHswMFFX

I tried to make the html variable private or have different html variables. I have stuck with it being public. This might be the cause of the issue, however I am unsure. I believe the issue has to do with duplicate html DOM manipulation.